# ValueError:too many values to unpack

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and, when I try to transform date time to mins, I get the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Here's my code:

```py
def t2m(t):
    m,s,l = t.strip().split(":")
    return int(m)+int(s)/60+int(l)/6000

a= "0000-00-00 00:12:46:13"
d=a.strip('0000-00-00 00')

print(round(t2m(d)),1)
```

Comment: the error shows at line 2

Comment: `d` is `:12:46:13`, and the result of the split is `['', '12', '46', '13']`, so, too many variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because `t.strip().split(":")` returns 4 values and you are trying to put them into `m,s,l`.

You should replace your second line with:

```py
_,m,s,l = t.strip().split(":")
```

Answer (score 1):

found out by myself.  should be like

```py
d=a.strip('0000-00-00 00：')
```